# Get Day Of Week in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I want to have the day of week in the variable `DOW`.

So I use the following bash-script:

```
DOM=$(date +%d)
DOW=($($DOM % 7) ) | sed 's/^0*//'
```

Unfortunately there I get this error: `bash: 09: command not found`. The expected result is 2 ( 9 % 7 = 2) in the variable `$DOW`.

How can I get this working? 
It works for the days 1-8 but because of the C-hex, there is no number over 8 available and the following message appears: `bash: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")`.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. If it is the day of the week, why you expect 2 from today Wednesday?

Comment: The main problem is that the bash `()` math expression parser wrongly assumes 0-prefixed numbers are octal, which is not a problem for 1-7, but bad for `08` and `09`.  Try `expr` instead.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Use `%u`. Like this:

```
DOW=$(date +%u)
```

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date):

> %u     day of week (1..7); 1 is Monday

Answer (score 7):

You can also use to return the day name

```
 date +'%A'
```

Answer (score 5):

This works fine here

```
#!/bin/sh
DOW=$(date +"%a")
echo $DOW
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a different %-specifier is the real answer to your question. The way to prevent bash from choking on invalid octal numbers is to tell it that you actually have a base-10 number:

```
$ DOM=09
$ echo $(( DOM % 7 ))
bash: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
$ echo $(( 10#$DOM % 7 ))
2
```

Answer (score 0):

The format option %u returns weekday number [1..7]. Monday is 1.

With date in string:

```
$ date -d "2022-07-17" +%u
7
```

Also check return value in $?.
For invalid date, $? is nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
# Week day:
[ $(date +%u) -lt 6 ] && echo "work day"


# Example
[ $(date -d "2023-03-25" +%u) -lt 6 ] && echo "work day"
# out nothing

[ $(date -d "2023-03-26" +%u) -lt 6 ] && echo "work day"
# out nothing

[ $(date -d "2023-03-27" +%u) -lt 6 ] && echo "work day"
# out work day


[ $(date -d "2023-03-31" +%u) -lt 6 ] && echo "work day"
# out work day
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use the `-` flag:

```
DOM=$(date +%-d)
             ^
```

which would prevent the day from being padded with `0`.

From `man date`:

```
   -      (hyphen) do not pad the field
```

Observe the difference:

```
$ DOM=$(date +%d)
$ echo $((DOM % 7))
bash: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
$ DOM=$(date +%-d)
$ echo $((DOM % 7))
2
```

Comment: The day of month modulo 7 is **not** the day of the week!