# How can we get weekday based on given date in unix

Tags: bash, shell, datetime, unix, unix-timestamp

From a given date in `%m-%d-%Y` format we should determine what day it is.

Example: for the date `09-01-2017` output should be `Friday`

Comment: Related (getting a numerical output instead of a word for weekday): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956516/getting-day-of-week-in-bash-script

Answer (score 6):

Very simple. Just use the date command itself  with correct options.

```
$ date -j -f '%m-%d-%Y' "09-01-2017" +'%A'
Friday
```

Comment: Since this is neither GNU `date` or BSD `date` you may want to specify what `date` it is. I'm guessing macOS?

Answer (score 4):

If you have your date like this:

```
d="09-01-2017"
```

you need to reformat it to "YYYY-MM-DD"

```
date -d $(echo $d|awk -F- '{print $3 "-" $1 "-" $2}') +%A # DOW
```

Comment: +A will ouput 'friday'

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I usually do. I would use the date function.
you can do 'man date' and find options.

```sh
$ d=2020-08-20 \
$ date -d "$d" +%u \
4 \
$ date -d "$d" +%A \
Thursday
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DayOfWeek=$(date +%A)
```

This would yield the day of week `monday-sunday`
If your input date is strictly in the format `MM-DD-YYYY`, use the following

```
IFS='-' read -ra ADDR <<< "09-01-2017"
formattedDate=${ADDR[2]}-${ADDR[0]}-${ADDR[1]}
date -d  $formattedDate +%A
```

The first line tokenizes the components of the date and the second rearranges them

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as %m/%d%Y which gets recognized by the date command.

```
$ date --date="`echo 09-01-2017| sed -e 's/-/\//g' `" +'%A'
Friday
```

To verify it, pass %F to get it in ISO format

```
$ date --date="`echo 09-01-2017| sed -e 's/-/\//g' `" +'%A %F'
Friday 2017-09-01
```

Answer (score -1):

```
date +%A
# let us see in a for loop
for i in {1..7}; do date +%A --date=+${i}day; done

Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
```